# How to use react-responsive as a const

Tags: reactjs, responsive

I'm new in react.js and I'm trying to add some responsive features to my first app using https://github.com/contra/react-responsive

So, it cool that I can use it as a wrapper to my content like

```
<MediaQuery maxDeviceWidth={767}>
   this will shown only on mobile
</MediaQuery>
```

But can I do some magic to use this feature like some constant?

```
const isMobile = MediaQuery < 768;
return <div className={isMobile ? "mobile" : "desktop"}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but I suppose you could just use the window width instead:

```
const isMobile = window.innerWidth < 768;
return <div className={ isMobile ? "mobile" : "desktop" }></div>;
```

If you want to update this on window resize then there's a bit more to it.

You would need to keep the **isMobile** value in the component state and then update the state when the window resizes, which will cause the component to re-render.

You would need something like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isMobile: window.innerWidth < 768
        };
    }

    updateIsMobile() {
        this.setState({
            isMobile: window.innerWidth < 768
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateIsMobile);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateIsMobile);
    }

    render() {
        return <div className={ this.state.isMobile ? "mobile" : "desktop" }></div>
    }

}
```

However, if it's just to set a CSS class though then you would probably be best just using CSS media queries.

Comment: will it changes on window resize?

Comment: That takes a bit more work. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the documentation, you can do this:

```
return (
    <MediaQuery maxDeviceWidth={767}>
        {isMobile => (
            <div className={isMobile ? 'mobile' : 'desktop'>
            </div>
        )}
    </MediaQuery>
);
```

If the children are a function, the function is used to generate the real children.